# LAMP ubuntu 18.04 com php 5.6 + php 7.2

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, lamp

Quero instalar LAMP num ubuntu 18.04 LTS com 2 versões de php: 5.6 e 7.2, e que possa alternar entre versões de php de uma forma prática.

Pesquisei mas só encontrei sobre a instalação do LAMP + PHP (1 versão) e não LAMP + PHP (2 versões)...
Sugestões?

Comment: Pode montar sua *Stack* usando *Docker* (um imagem com LAMP para cada versão do *php*). Ou usar um gerenciador de versões pro *php* ([phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv) e [virtphp](http://virtphp.org/)). **obs:** não usei esses gerenciadores de versão ainda, são apenas sugestões, infelizmente (*ou felizmente*) não programo em *php* :p